# Extract exponent from double as unsigned value

Tags: c

Hi I have a problem with one of exercise from codewars site. My job is to extract exponent from double value as a unsigned number. But I am not allowed to use any arithmetic and binary operation and include any extra files. So then i cant use charcters: +-*/%&|^~<>#?. I think that only way to solve this problem is using functions. Can you give me some advice how to do this task plase

```
int exponent(double d)
{
  int result;
  frexp(d,&result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Please give a sample input and sample expected output. Also, please post whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: i try to use frexp function but it gave me exponent as a signed value i have no idea how to convert it to unsigned value

Comment: @gawiellus Perhaps `unsigned exponent(double d) { int *result; frexp(d,&result); return result; }`?

Comment: @gawiellus With "it gave me exponent as a signed value i have no idea how to convert it to unsigned value", --> implies  answers here will be too advanced.

Comment: it doesn't work properly because i have already try

Comment: gawiellus `frexp(double value, int *exp)` expects an `int *`, not `&result` which is a `unsigned *`.

Comment: gawiellus Rather code with the limitations, first write code the functions correctly.  _Then_ try to re-write code with limitations.

Comment: chux but you can give me some clues. I don't need answer i need some valuables advice. What to read?

Comment: @gawiellus To convert an `int` to `unsigned`, you need some basic C text book.  For `frexp()`, see [frexp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/frexp)

Comment: Probably my question was bad because I am not english speaker. The problem is that function frexp give me exponent as a number from range -1022 to 1023 and my task is to return number from 0 to 2045 and I can't using any arithmetics operations

Comment: Research `union`, _bit fields_ and [Double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: thx chux I will try

Comment: `<` and `>` are relational operators, not math operators.

Comment: Yes ok but I can't use this.I can't use any bitwise arithmetics operators any pointer/address operation and can't include any extra files.
Have you got any clues? I even can't use above instructions frexp(d,&result) because of character &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I have not tested the following, so it may need some 'tweaking'

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union 
{
    double f;
    struct 
    {
        uint64_t mantisa : 52;
        uint64_t exponent : 11;
        uint64_t sign : 1;
    } parts;
} double_cast;

uint64_t normalizedExponent(double d)
{
    double_cast mydouble.f = d; 

    return ( mydouble.parts.sign )? mydouble.parts.exponent << 1:  mydouble.parts.exponent;

}
```

Comment: Thank you I think it can help